# Can I make test cases for web application security testing?

Tags: security-testing, jira

We have been performing application security testing based on OWASP standards. We use JIRA to report the bugs or improvements. However, is there any way where we can make a generic test case for these type of testing, so that it becomes part of my release and deployment certification process and becomes audit ready record.

Comment: You can take a look at the Software Assurance Reference Dataset http://samate.nist.gov/SARD/index.php - These are effectively vulnerable code snippets for multiple programming languages and include the OWASP top 10 vulnerabilities. However, if you want to try live examples you can try a number of opensource or commercial wargame apps: [Owasp WebGoat](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebGoat_Project) [Damn Vulnerable Web Application](http://www.dvwa.co.uk/)

Comment: Jira bug types are basically free text entries - it should be trivial to write anything you want. Are you experiencing any problem in particular?

Answer (score 0):

Automate this with some kind of static code analyzer tool (e.g. SonarQube) which has OWASP checks included.

Comment: It will help me in code review. However, I would want security testing to be a part of release management. In order to this we need some basic test cases to be added.